# Distribute Qt symbian app other than in OVI store

Tags: qt, distribution, publish

I have a Express signed Symbian app, developed in Qt. I don't want to publish it in Nokia OVI store. I want to distribute the app to some particular people only. What should I do?

I think uploading the SIS file in my website and provide a link to download the app is not a feasible solution in my case.

Can I just mail the SIS file to those set of people? Or is there anything like "Targeted Distribution" (like in the case of Windows Phone) for Qt apps?

Comment: Mailing won't do, Symbian's mail agents don't allow installing received attachments as applications. Serving the SIS file on a website is the only way of Over-The-Air provisioning AFAIK. Why is it "not a feasible solution" for you?

Comment: @Pavel Zdenek - Thanks for your reply. I want to distribute my app to some people only and not to any others. So serving my SIS file in a website is not a good idea, right.? What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i correct my previous statement about unusability of email distribution. I based that assumption on the path i had to take for enabling a limited distribution some time ago (that is, a web download). Have a look at the following URL

http://my-symbian.com/s60/faq/showquestion.php?faq=4&fldAuto=13

1. If your target user has Nokia PC Suite, you can deliver the file to him in any way, but he needs to know how to install SISX with the Suite.
2. IR/Bluetooth probably doesn't apply, you want to do distribution not point-to-point.
3. "Physical" distribution over MMC is perhaps too cumbersome for you
4. If your target user has email reading set up on his phone, you indeed can send him an email with SISX in attachment. This means *real Symbian native email agent* not "reading webmail over browser" - you would lose a crucial MIME type of the attachment that way. See below.
5. The widest applicable method, webpage OTA. If you need to restrict the access, you can always set up HTTP authentication on that webpage and let your target users know the name and password. **However there is one crucial step for this to work**: you need to override the MIME type of SISX HTTP download. By default, *application/octet-stream* will be assigned by a generic webserver, which won't work. [You need to do some HTTP response hacking](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Archived%3aHow_to_enable_OTA_%28Over_The_Air%29_SIS_install_from_your_website).

Comment: Thank u so much. Your answer helps me a lot. I'll go with the OTA method. In that link, instructions are there to enable OTA for S60 1st, 2nd & 3rd edition. But what about Symbian Belle or Anna? Is the procedures are same..?

Comment: I have no experience with these newer platforms. But i think that it should work too, unless Symbian changed MIME type or security model (so that OTA of 3rd party apps would be disabled altogether)

Comment: Anyways, I'll have a try. Thanks again.